# How can i import Excel Data Into My Sql Server Table Only Using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I am new to using stored procedures
I have an excel file that has few columns and data.
I want to be able to read and insert the rows in respective columns in the table, but only using Stored procedures.
I am using sql server 2017

Comment: A simple internet search will find many, many discussions of importing information from excel files.

Comment: [Import data from Excel to SQL Server or Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017#openrowset). That said, I'm voting to close this question as too broad.

Comment: @SMor i posted this question after intensively searching..... also i wanted to know how to resolve my query using only stored procedures...  i found many that used mvc, c# interface to achieve the task but i found none that did the same with only stored procedures

Answer (score 1):

A way you can easily do this is to save the excel file in CSV format then using Bulk Insert in the Stored Procedure. Bulk Insert, I think, doesn't accept parameters as the file location so you might also need to write the bulk insert script as a dynamic-SQL.